# Relative path in local-exec

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to reference a local script inside a local-exec provisioner. The script is located several levels above the module directory. Using `${path.module}/../../scripts/somescript.ps1` generates a `path not found` error.

Moving the scripts directory under the modules directory solves the problem but unfortunately is not a valid option in my case. Working scenario: `${path.module}/scripts/somescript.ps1`

I didn't see anywhere that it's a TF limitation or a bug so, any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

This is my local-exec block:

```
provisioner "local-exec" { 
interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"] 
command = "${path.module}/scripts/Generate-SQLInfo.ps1 -user ${var.az_sql_server_admin_login} -dbname ${var.az_sql_db_name} -resourceGroupName ${module.resource_group.az_resource_group_name} -sqlServerName ${module.sql_server.sql_server_name} -vaultName ${module.keyvault.az_keyvault_name} -azSubscriptionID ${var.az_subscription_id}"
 }
```

Comment: Can you share an [mcve] please? The most important thing here is the structure of your code base.

Comment: Show us your local-exec block how you are trying to run the command.

Comment: Hi @Nagashayan,
This is my local-exec block:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
    command     = "${path.module}/scripts/Generate-SQLInfo.ps1 -user ${var.az_sql_server_admin_login} -dbname ${var.az_sql_db_name} -resourceGroupName ${module.resource_group.az_resource_group_name} -sqlServerName ${module.sql_server.sql_server_name} -vaultName ${module.keyvault.az_keyvault_name} -azSubscriptionID ${var.az_subscription_id}"
  }

```

Comment: @MaximDavidov you can edit your initial question to expand it to include additional information that others ask you for in comments. That's the better way to do it so that the new content is readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using working_dir

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html

```
provisioner "local-exec" { 
  working_dir = "${path.module}/../scripts/" # assuming it's this directory
  interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"] 
  command = "Generate-SQLInfo.ps1 ..."
 }
```

I don't have resources right now to test this but probably this should work for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @Nagashayan