# Running Powershell script in Terraform module

Tags: linux, powershell, terraform

Am currently running some Terraform to create resources in Azure.  We have a module we have written to create a resource group with a bunch of variables.  The provider currently does not allow the creation of budgets and cost alerts but the Powershell modules do.  I thought we could then add a Powershell script to carry out the settings.  I seem to be hitting a snag where I cannot quite work out how to address the Powershell script.  I have the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "PowerShellScriptRunAlways" {
    triggers = {
        always_run = "${timestamp()}"
    }

    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = ".'${path.module}//pwsh//costalert.ps1 -subscriptionID \"${var.azure_subscription_id}\" -tenantID \"${var.azure_tenant_id}\" -clientID \"${var.azure_client_id}\" -clientSecret \"${var.azure_client_secret}\" -budgetAmount \"${var.budgetAmount}\" -rgName \"${azurerm_resource_group.this.name}\" -emailAddresses \"${var.emailAddresses}\"'"
        interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
    }
}
```

using pwsh as this is running on a Linux Jenkins agent.  This is part of a module where the ps1 file is under "root module directory/pwsh" but it seems to yield the following:

```
Error: Error running command '.'.terraform/modules/rg_test\pwsh\costalert.ps1 -subscriptionID "xxxxx" -tenantID "xxxxxxx" -clientID "xxxxxx" -clientSecret "xxxxx" -budgetAmount "1000" -rgName "rg-da_test-sbxeng-001" -emailAddresses "xxxxxx"'': exit status 1. Output: . : The module '.terraform/modules/rg_test' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module .terraform/modules/rg_test
+ .'.terraform/modules/rg_test\pwsh\costalert.ps1 -subscriptionID
```

It seems to be switching the path but cannot seem to make it pick up the script and run it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this a quoting issue?

I can successfully execute this `pwsh` null resource from a terraform module in an Azure DevOps linux agent. Note that only the script path is single quoted, while in your example you've got the whole command single quoted.

```
resource "null_resource" "create_sql_user" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = ".'${path.module}\\scripts\\create-sql-user.ps1' -password \"${random_password.sql_password.result}\" -username \"${var.sql_username}\" -sqlSaConnectionString \"${var.sql_server_connectionstring}\" -databaseName \"${azurerm_sql_database.db.name}\" "
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_sql_database.db]
}
```

Comment: hmmm have adjust but still get the same.  is the first "." there as a dot source or as an indication of executing from the current directory?

Comment: I am not really sure. You could also try `working_dir` as specified here, might be a cleaner option than the quoting shenanigans we're both doing. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679852/relative-path-in-local-exec

Comment: ah ok so combination of things.  updated the single quote as you described but also had to replace "\\" with "/" after {path.module}.  Finally had removed the workspace cleanup stanza to help troubleshoot so was not actually pulling new changes.

Comment: Glad to have lead you to a working solution. :) If you can post the final working `command` string, I'll update the answer with: When running on Linux Jenkins node ... reference the script as such.